# ESB service client creation

Tags: java, service, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I need to develop a graphical client for exchange information with the server, where a service runs (wso2 esb). I have no knowledge about it except that it exchanges information in XML as I understand. 
I am planning the client in Java. And I dont need to deal with the server side of the stuff. How does the client communicate with the bus? +
WHat are the steps to get messages from the bus? +
What can I read about it (the problem is I have knowledge of Servlets and other web components - i dont know anything about ejbs except they are object in the ejb container) -  how can I at least understand what services are like?

Comment: You should ask those questions to the folks running the ESB. No one here knows e.g. which services are hosted a and how security in your environment works.

Comment: Could you at least explain what a service is? By the way it has some components called sequence mesiator and endpoint - in order to run the client - do I need to implement the endpoint +

Comment: THe backbone is APacheMQ + JMS - i dont know how it is related - but I got some scarce info about it. I dont even know what to ask from them..do I need to ask what messages are sent?

Comment: 'Service' is a very broad term. It may mean SOAP web services, defined by one or more WSDL and/or XSD documents. Did you read their [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB/Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation)?

Comment: Apologies, but IMHO your questions are fairly broad... in general you must understand which services you have to use, where to get the specification, and how non-functional aspects work, e.g. security, message protocols (SOAP/HTTP, SOAP/JMS, JSON, plain XML, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Artem, 
 As a start you need to do is:
  1. Ask for information about how to access the (web-)service. (more specifically WSDL)
  2. If they are running Wso2 Esb, its very easy to generate client side code ( in java) using just a few clicks ( so ask for that too !)
  3. Once you have auto generated code you can develop GUI on top of it.

For more information about generating client side code refer to:
 http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/WSDL2Java